# Send email with an attachment in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, relative-path, filepath

I am using the Codeigniter library to send an email with an attachment, the file I want to attach is in the following directory

```
/uploads/pdf/yourfile.pdf
```

How would I attach this in relation to its fullpath? E.g How can I find the correct path (not URL) for this file.

```
 $this->email->attach('/path/uploads/pdf/yourfile.pdf');
```

How can I determine what should replace 'path' in the line above

Comment: I think you are after `BASEPATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to use CodeIgniters functionality to do the following..

```
 $path = set_realpath('uploads/pdf/');
 $this->email->attach($path . 'yourfile.pdf');
```

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks again

note : Don't forget to load the path helper before, otherwise the `set_realpath()` will not exists.

Answer (score 4):

you can have the directory where your script is running by `__DIR__` magic constant or `dirname(__FILE__)` in older versions of PHP and then determine your path from this point. Then you can use `realpath()` to have a resolved path to your file. for example:

```
$path_to_the_file = realpath(__DIR__.'/../uploads/pdf/yourfile.pdf/');
```

first try to `echo __DIR__` to find your current location and then add a relative path from your current location to `__DIR__` and feed it to `realpath()`

Also in Codeigniter, the constant APPPATH points to the application folder, so this is another solution:

```
$path_to_the_file = realpath(APPPATH.'relative/path/to/the/file/from/application/folder');
```

Comment: How would I access the path that is one level up from the application folder?

Comment: just like this : realpath(APPPATH.'/../this_is_one_level_upper');